# Block WampServer homepage from remote machine

Tags: php, wampserver

Is there any way that I can block WampServer home page to be accessible from a remote machine (over a LAN) but still I want folders to be accessible.

Eg : I want : http://192.168.127.98 to be blocked

and http://192.168.127.98/website/ to be accessible

Comment: You just use a Directory or Location config block and put different Allow/Deny rules for different locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Quentin, you saved my day. I edited httpd.conf

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/website">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and it works like a charm

Comment: The wamp home page is blocked but my website is also forbidden too. what i am doing wrong?

Comment: even on my pc i am unable to access homepage

Comment: I did the same but it allows everything in my PC but remote users cannot acces both home page and website